# MPChart Android LimitLine not showing in react native

Tags: android, react-native, mpandroidchart

I tried applying using the limitLine in the LineChart chart but had no luck. Here is what I tried in the JSX:-

```
<LineChart  style={styles.chartM} data={this.getWeekData(false)} description={"Week Wise"} 
                  visibleXRange={[0,30]}
                  maxVisibleValueCount={50} 
                  xAxis={{drawGridLines:false, gridLineWidth:1, position:"BOTTOM", spaceBetweenLabels:0, labelRotationAngle:-30.0, limitLines:[{ limit: 115, lineColor: processColor('red'), lineWidth: 2}]}}
                  yAxisRight={{enable:false}} 
                  yAxis={{startAtZero:false,drawGridLines:false,position:"INSIDE_CHART"}}
                  drawGridBackground={true}
                  backgroundColor={"#f2f2f2"} 
                  legend={{enable:true, position:'ABOVE_CHART_RIGHT', direction:"LEFT_TO_RIGHT"}}
                  gridBackgroundColor={"#f2f2f2"} 
                  scaleEnabled={false}/>
```

The limitLine was expected to appear at 115, but somehow does not appear even after the limitLine props have been set.